# npm install failing errno -4058 while attempting 'npm install' from 'ng new' command

Tags: angular, npm

I was recently starting a new project on Angular and to do so needed to install the packages in my package.json file. The package.json file is the one you get from 'ng new '. I have tried countless times to try to get this to work, but I consistently get the same result on both of my computers and I have no idea why. I have dumped several hours into this, but don't plan on giving up. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I will provide details below.

## Details:

- Running 'npm -v' gives me: 5.6.0
- running 'node -v' gives me: v8.10.0
- I have already run 'npm i -g @angular/cli' successfully

## Problem:

- I try to run npm install, it executes for a while, then I get the following error:

  **npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Project\FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'D:\Project\FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules.typescript.DELETE'**

## What I have already tried:

- Uninstalling nodejs, reinstalling, 'npm i -g @angular/cli', 'npm i' (no good)
- Running 'npm i' several times (I read about possbile race conditions) (no good)
- Tried doing what the error said (the file doesn't actually exist) (no good)
- Tried starting another new project from scratch (no good)
- Tried 'npm uninstall -g @angular/cli', 'npm cache clear --force', 'npm install -g @angular/cli', 'npm install' (no good)
- And lastly I tried the guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10027)

I am getting pretty desperate at this point, as I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. (I've gotten this to work before!!) Any advice would be helpful. ANY. Once again, the package.json file is generated from the 'ng new' command, but I can post it here if needed.
(And before anyone asks, it is not because it is on the D:/ drive, it does the same thing on the C:/ drive.)

## package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have solved your problem may be useful for someone else :

[npm-install-fails-on-windows-10-enoent-4058](https://blog.josequinto.com/2017/06/23/npm-install-fails-on-windows-10-enoent-4058-operation-not-permitted-rename/#Problem)

But meanwhile just try :

> npm cache clear --force